# How could I have accidentally changed the score on a deleted answer?

Tags: bug, votes

There are some deleted answers in [Does Hebrews 1:1-2 teach that Jehovah in the OT is always the Father?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44701/does-hebrews-11-2-teach-that-jehovah-in-the-ot-is-always-the-father).

I clicked on the "2" score of the first one in order to see the plus and minus votes, and the number changed to "3".
(I did the second one too, to confirm that it had in fact changed and that I hadn't accidentally clicked the up-vote button.)

I reloaded the page and the two "3"s remain.

What's going wrong?

Comment: What _also_ went wrong appears to me to be a single individual deleting two good answers (which already had votes) and a third user deleting their own answer because the question was substantially altered.

Comment: @NigelJ It would have been better if some kind of commentary had been left explaining those answer deletions, but on balance since the Q changed they are about completely different passages. I suppose this is where the right point of frustration is that the OP was more interested in their hobby topic than they were in the passage they were asking about! Happy to undelete if there's a consensus.

Comment: Ray - I don't really know what to tell you, I've tried the same steps and can't reproduce it myself. Seems to just have been an ephemeral thing. I haven't seen that behaviour happen before.